# Alternative for Promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am currently using `Promise.allSettled` to wait for all my promises to finish(irrespective of whether they resolve or get rejected).

Since my project is compliant to `Node v12.3.1` I am unable to use this?
What other simple alternatives can I use.

Sample code:

```
async function runner() {
    let promises = [];
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
        promises.push(fetcher())
    }
    await Promise.allSettled(promises).then(([results]) => console.log(results.length));
    console.log('continue work...');
}
```

**Note**:
Promise.allSettled is available from `Node version >12.9`.
Adding shims is also not an option.

Comment: "*Adding shims is also not an option.*" then what solutions do you expect? All of them would basically be a variation of "make your own `allSettled`"

Comment: By adding shims I meant, not allowed to make changes to package.json. I am open to small snippets that I can add.

Comment: Bit new to nodejs so please bare with me.

Comment: Pick a well known and used and tested polyfill and copy/paste the code, then? All the packages you'd be adding are going to be open source anyway. You can visit their GitHub and just see what the code is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a small polyfill trick that you can do manually to simulate the effects of `Promise.allSettled`.

Here's the snippet.

```js
if (!Promise.allSettled) {
  Promise.allSettled = promises =>
    Promise.all(
      promises.map((promise, i) =>
        promise
          .then(value => ({
            status: "fulfilled",
            value,
          }))
          .catch(reason => ({
            status: "rejected",
            reason,
          }))
      )
    );
}

Promise.allSettled(promises).then(console.log);
```

That means map all of the promises, then return the results, either successful or rejected.

An alternative, if you do not want the object-like nature of `Promise.all`, the following snippet may help. This is very simple, you just need to add `.catch` method here.

```js
const promises = [
  fetch('/something'),
  fetch('/something'),
  fetch('/something'),
].map(p => p.catch(e => e)); // this will prevent the promise from breaking out, but there will be no 'result-object', unlike the first solution.

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: I'd replace `.then(value => ({ status: "fulfilled", value, })).catch(reason => ({ status: "rejected", reason, }))` with `.then(value => ({ status: "fulfilled", value, }), reason => ({ status: "rejected", reason, }))`.

Comment: In StackOverflow, the best way to thank someone is to mark their answer as accepted if it helps you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Returns a promise that is resolved after all the promises given have been fulfilled or rejected, with a series of objects that describe the result of each promise.

Library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-ax

Example:

```
const { createPromise } = require('promise-ax');
const promiseAx = createPromise();
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(4);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, new Error("error")));
const promise3 = Promise.reject("error");
const promise4 = promiseAx.resolve(8);
const promise5 = promiseAx.reject("errorAx");
const asyncOperation = (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (time < 0) {
            reject("reject");
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(time);
        }, time);
    });
};
const promisesToMake = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4, promise5, asyncOperation(100)];
promiseAx.allSettled(promisesToMake).then((results) =>   results.forEach((result) => console.log(result)));
// Salida esperada:
// 4
// Error: error
// error
// 8
// errorAx
// 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
await (Promise as any).allSettled(promises).then(console.log);
```

This works in typescript.

Comment: depending on the browser engine one might get different results, the code itself is syntactically correct but when I used it got a Promise.allsettled is not a function. Its quite a new api so full support is not yet added